# Identity operators in Swift

Tags: swift

If a is identical to c, b is identical to c, why a is not identical to b?

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = a
var c = a[0...2]
a === c                    // true
b === c                    // true
a === b                    // false
```

If a, b, c are constants:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = a
let c = a[0...2]
a === c                    // true
b === c                    // true
a === b                    // true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @onevcat said, it's might be a bug of Playground. And if you change `a` to objects of reference type, all the identity tests will be `true`.

```
class K {}
var a = [K(), K(), K()]
var b = a
var c = a[0...2]
a === c                    // true
b === c                    // true
a === b                    // true
```

it means that `a`, `b` & `c` share the same storage and elements.

Comment: Thank you and @onevcat. I copied my code to a .swift file and ran it in terminal, all tests true.

Comment: Radar filed: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6240029269557248 rdar://17192099

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `import Cocoa` or `import UIKit` if you are playing with PlayGround to make it correct. It seems there is some type map thing in the Cocoa framework to mess things up. It should be a bug, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, my guess is that since `c` is a `var` in the first case, its mutable and thus it has to make a copy. That way if you add on to `c` it wouldn't modify `a`. In the second case, they are all immutable so they can point to the same memory space